# Does git clean support anchored patterns?

Tags: git

I want to remove all untracked files, including all 'out' directories in my source tree but not the 'out' directory in the root of the source tree.

Based on the patterns supported by .gitignore, I expected that something like this would work:

```
git clean -xdf -e /out/
```

but it does not. the 'out' directory in the root of the source tree is removed.
Leaving the initial '/' out does not remove any 'out' directory.
So I am stuck. Should I file a bug against git?
I can use some other means to achieve the same thing, but git clean was rather fast and powerful.

Comment: ...why not just _first move_ the `out` dir manually to somewhere safe, then run `git clean`, then move the `out` directory back?

Answer (score 1):

When I do

```
mkdir -p jojo t/jojo
>jojo/KILROY
>t/jojo/KILROY
git clean -dnxe /jojo/ | grep jojo
```

I get

```
would remove t/jojo/
```

so it works for me, it's time to play spot-the-differences. I'm on a current Git.

Comment: What do you mean it works for me? You have just proven that it doesn't. /jojo/ does not match /t/jojo/ in .gitignore. Or in any ANCHORED match.

Comment: It's removing the deeper directories but not the one at the root of the source tree."all 'out' directories in my source tree but not the 'out' directory in the root of the source tree."

Comment: I apologize, I forgot what I was after since I filed this question. What git are you on? For me this is the output:
`$ git clean -dnxe /jojo/

Would remove jojo/

Would remove t/`

I am on git version 2.41.0.windows.3.

Comment: Just built 2.41.0 on my linux install, it gives the same for me as it did before. Since the `x` option shuts off all but explicit excludes there's just that one pattern, and something very wrong here. Googling gets no hits. Was the `t/` in your quoted ouptut truncated, and really `t/jojo/`? I'm assuming it was really `t/jojo/`, yes?  I don't keep a windows install, but there's something very wrong here, either way this can't be case-sensitivity if you're c&p'ing and not retyping. Try `git ls-files -ocix/jojo/`, what's that list?

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick. `git clean -dfx` does not remove an untracked nested git repository unless an extra `-f` is specified. So, you can turn the folder into a git repository with `git init` to prevent it from being removed by `git clean -dfx`.